# Is there a keyboard shortcut to cycle through open documents in Geany?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, geany

I have multiple documents open in Geany. I can see them listed in the sidebar under the "Documents" tab. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches me from the current document to the previous but I don't know of any way to cycle through the documents in a sequence.

Can this be done using Geany? Is there a plugin for this by any chance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Switch to left document     Ctrl-PageUp (C)     Switches to the previous open document.
Switch to right document    Ctrl-PageDown (C)   Switches to the next open document.
Switch to last used document    Ctrl-Tab    Switches to the previously shown document (if it's still open). Holding Ctrl (or another modifier if the keybinding has been changed) will show a dialog, then repeated presses of the keybinding will switch to the 2nd-last used document, 3rd-last, etc. Also known as Most-Recently-Used documents switching.
Move document left  Ctrl-Shift-PageUp   Changes the current document with the left hand one.
Move document right     Ctrl-Shift-PageDown     Changes the current document with the right hand one.
Move document first         Moves the current document to the first position.
Move document last      Moves the current document to the last position.
```

[notebook-tab-keybindings for Geany](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#notebook-tab-keybindings)

Comment: It most certainly does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking about or not, but on my system pressing ALT+1, ALT+2, etc. will select currently open documents, much the same as clicking on the tabs with the mouse (note that the left-most document tab corresponds to ALT+1, and so on). Most other apps, such as web browsers, seem to use the CTRL key as the modifier to directly select an open tab, so if ALT doesn't do the trick on your system try CTRL as the modifier key instead!

Hope this helped!