# Geany: can I set a shortcut key to the Addons plugin 'Show Document List' in the toolbar?

Tags: ide, editor, geany

I want a quick way to view and select from open files, listed in alphabetic order, without using a mouse.

I can do this in the sidebar documents list, and have setup shortcuts to make viewing/hiding this fast.

But ideally I want to just pull up a quick drop down without having the sidebar visible. Absolutely ideally would also be not having the toolbar visible, but I can live with that. I do not want to have the editor tabs visible.

The Addons plugin 'Show Document List' is almost perfect, but I can't find any way to set a shortcut key to it.

Coming from Scite I am looking for similar functionality to alt-b to bring up open buffers.

Any other ideas on mouse-less document switching also welcome.

I am aware of cycling through documents in tab order, but I want to do this in alphabetic order, and I want a list of documents. I know about alt-1 etc but this doesn't suit my needs either, as you have to be aware of which document is in which tab.

I do use alt-tab to switch between two latest documents.

[Is there a keyboard shortcut to cycle through open documents in Geany?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3734897/1175459) does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

The document list of addons plugin is not yet available via keystroke. (not implemented)